# Add lots of data to Google App Engine NDB (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm working on a project that requires me to import lots of data (on the scale of tens of thousands of entities) into the Google App Engine NDB.

The data is stored in a text file, for which I wrote a parsing program that generates a list of the entities found in the file, which I then write into the database using the `put_multi()` method.

When I apply this to testing data sets of say a couple hundred up to about a thousand entries, it works fine; applying it to the real data set (at about 30,000 entries right now, but it will grow), however, throws a `DeadlineExceededError`. I'm guessing that means the program is running too long and App Engine cuts it off.

So my question is, how do I run code that takes a long time to complete while it iterates over a bunch of data?

I've read something about a task queue or something, but that seems to be more aimed at a short task that needs to be repeated a bunch of times (while, here, I'm really just waiting for the `put_multi()` to complete).

It's also a pretty bad UX having the page take this long to load. Is there any way for me to have my code that runs when the user initializes the data import just sort of kickstart the actual parsing and writing code behind the scenes on the server while the user gets a page back that says the data is being processed in the background?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a put_multi_async(), which will take like 10 ms to complete and then do the put in the background.  You're still limited by the datastore deadline, which :

> The default deadline is 60 seconds
>   (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Data_consistency)

you might need to spread your async puts in different calls (maybe a couple of thousand each, write speed will depend on the exact size of your entity)

EDIT : as per mgilson's comment,

> > You're also limited by memory restrictions. If you have enough memory to pull in the entire file, then task-queues might be the answer (put a bunch of different pieces of the file into different tasks)

Comment: You're also limited by memory restrictions.  If you have enough memory to pull in the entire file, then task-queues might be the answer (put a bunch of different pieces of the file into different tasks)

Comment: @mgilson I will edit my answer with your comment to make sure people see both, if you don't mind

Comment: Sure.  Consider that comment (and any other comment I make on SO) to be licensed in the public domain ;-)

Comment: So I should take the list of entries, split it up into lists of about 1000 entries each, and loop through those lists calling `put_multi_async()` ~30 times?

Comment: could be an idea.  You have 60 seconds per put_multi_async.  I would do some tests to see how "long" you need your code to work, but 1000 each seems a good size

Comment: Ah, ok. I haven't really done any asynchronous programming before, so let me just make sure I'm understanding this right. Each `put_multi_async()` will take only 10 ms to complete, so if I loop through 30 of them, that'll take .3 seconds, and then the rest of my code continues while my entries are being written into the database in the background, right? And as long as each `put_mutli_async()` doesn't take more than 60 seconds, it doesn't matter that 30 of them are running at pretty much the same time? Thanks.

Comment: @Leon Overweel exactly, put_multi_async at 10ms is just me ballparking it (it's a very fast call), but it sends your put request to the background where it gets handled whenever the code can do it.  As long as each put_multi_async finishes in a minute, you're good. I'm not sure if the system will queue them one after another, push each put to a different server, or run them on different threads, but it'll be in the background for sure.  (check https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/async)

Comment: You need to make sure that you put this either in an ndb.toplevel call or explicitly wait on the calls at the end. It is possible for an async call to not get sent and for your program to exit. Also note that there is a limit on the number of outstanding requests in a single request, so there will be a limit to how much this scales. If you use task queues to split up your data (then use async puts within each task) you can scale past that point.

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly what the task queue is for: long-running tasks that can't complete within the normal timeout. You should write a request handler that uploads the file then triggers the task.

An even more scalable way would be to use the [mapreduce framework](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/) to distribute your task among many workers.

Comment: The mapreduce framework says it's still experimental--so I can't build something that's guaranteed to keep working in the future on it, can I?

Comment: means they can change the framework to a point some functions will change/disappear.  If you want code that you NEVER have to go refactor for these changes, yeah mapreduce might not be for you.  It would still be a very easy thing to do with mapreduce though

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll learn how to do that if the `put_multi_async()` doesn't work out.